# Picasso doesn't call onError when phone is offline and it cannot load image

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso

I have this implementation of image loading with Picasso. I want it shows a progress bar while loading the image from URL. When it is loading, the progress bar is hidden. If it can't, I want it shows the error image instead and even then hide the ProgressBar.

But if there isn't network connection it never calls onError and the ProgressBar is always visible.

```
public class PicassoShowImageHideProgressBarCallback extends Callback.EmptyCallback {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private static final String TAG = "PicassoShowImageHidePro";

    public PicassoShowImageHideProgressBarCallback(ImageView imageView,
            ProgressBar progressBar) {
        mImageView = imageView;
        mProgressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@BindView(R.id.poster_image)
ImageView mImageView;

@BindView(R.id.pb_progress_loading)
ProgressBar mProgressBar;

Picasso.with(mContext).load(path).error(R.drawable.ic_error).into(mImageView,
                new PicassoShowImageHideProgressBarCallback(mImageView, mProgressBar));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885561/does-picasso-library-for-android-handle-image-loading-while-network-connectivity

Comment: @AnuragAggarwal I have seen this post, but I don't want to use image cache, alias, I want to, but when there is no image in cache I want to hide the progress bar and shows error image.

Comment: Does your `R.drawable.ic_error` load into the ImageView?

Comment: I Never see it when implementing this way. I only see it when I don't make use of Callback.

Answer (score 0):

[Does Picasso library for Android handle image loading while network connectivity is off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885561/does-picasso-library-for-android-handle-image-loading-while-network-connectivity)

Please take a look at the above link regarding the same issue .

Comment: It not works... onError method is never called. I have tried it before.

Comment: private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
} You can use it to check if device is online or offline . If its offlne then no need to initiate picasso call